# Escape filenames for applescript

Tags: python, escaping, applescript

I want to add list of mp3 files to iTunes via a applescript. The list of files is generated in python, where I also construct the applescripts. Here one example:

```
osascript -e tell application "iTunes"  ...
to add POSIX file "SomeMP3FileWithSpecialCharacters"!$%&$.mp3"
```

But if the file name contains special characters, it does not work. I think I have to escape the filenames in Python for applescript. So how would I do that the most pythonic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you might want to try would be to cast your entire path to a string:

```
str('filepath_here')
```

If that doesn't work, probably the next easiest way would be to use python's regular expressions module like so:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.escape('filepath_with_bad_characters!//%')
'filepath\\_with\\_bad\\_characters\\!\\/\\/\\%'
```

Alternately, you could use `re.sub` to only escape certain characters.  The [re module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) has more information.